# Increment variable in python while printing in file

Tags: python

Hi guys so i have this short piece of code where while the program is running I'm priting every key that I press on my keyboard in a file, one per line.
The thing is that i would like that each line has an ID, and that ID has, obviously, to be diferent everytime and i thought that the easier way was to to make this id to be an int that increments after every write operation; but i just can't get it to work, it always print the same int.

```
# detect key press
def on_press(key, myint=0):
    try:
        f = open("logger.txt", "a")
        upper = str(key.char).upper()
        f.write('{' + '"KeyPressed"' + ':' + '"' + upper + '","_id":"' + str(myint) + '"},' '\n')
        myint += 1
        f.close()
...

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

In this case if I run the program and press: A S D
the output is:

```
{"KeyPressed":"A","_id":"0"},
{"KeyPressed":"S","_id":"0"},
{"KeyPressed":"D","_id":"0"},
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal?

Comment: Shouldn't myint be a variable outside the function scope? You are not returning the increment in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time `on_press` is called, it gets a new copy of `myint`, as opposed to using a persistent copy that changes.

You can fix it with a simple closure that saves the state in a parent function:

```
def get_on_press(myint=0):
    def on_press(key):
        nonlocal myint
        print("on_press:  key: {}  myint: {}".format(key, myint))
        myint += 1
    return on_press

on_press = get_on_press()
```

You can then call `on_press` normally:

```
>>> on_press("a")
on_press:  key: a  myint: 0
>>> on_press("b")
on_press:  key: b  myint: 1
>>> on_press("c")
on_press:  key: c  myint: 2
>>>
```

Comment: There are multiple other ways to solve the problem. You could use a global variable; or an attribute of the function; or you could convert the function to a method of some class and then use either a class or instance attribute.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, although I like the idea of being able to have multiple instances with their own independent counters.  The class solution is also a good way to do it.